# Object is not iterable - NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

My following NodeJS program gives me the error when I try to print them it stops at `dataGood`, because it is not iterable.

### JSON

```
{"name":"something,cool", "user": "Awesome,Great"}
```

### Script

```
if(fs.existsSync('./data/data.json')){
  let data =  fs.readFileSync('./data/data.json');
  let dataGood = JSON.parse(data);
  let nameGood = [];
  let userGood = [];
  for(const element of dataGood){
      let name = [] = element.name;
      let user = [] = element.user;
      let nameSplit = name.toString().split(',')
      let userSplit = user.toString().split(',');
      nameGood = nameSplit;
      userGood = userSplit;
  }
console.log(nameGood, userGood)
}
```

### Error

```
TypeError: dataGood is not iterable
```

### Objective

I want to bring the "name" and "user" from JSON into those two arrays, and split them by comma.

```
//After script runs
nameGood  = ['something','cool']
userGood  = ['Awesome','Great']
```

Comment: Why do you want to iterate over an object? What do you expect to happen?

Comment: notice the difference between [for ... in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) and [for ... of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)

Comment: What should I do then?

Comment: *"What should I do then?"* It's unclear what you are trying to achieve. The data shows a single object with `name` and `user` properties. You seem to be accessing both properties in the loop (`element.name`, `element.user`). So it doesn't seem there is anything to iterating over? There is no array of objects and you don't seem to want to iterate over each property individually. Why do you have that loop?

Comment: I want to bring the "name" and "user" into those two arrays, and split them by comma. sorry if I was not clear. This used to work before but now when I am trying it does not anymore

Comment: A Javascript object by itself is NOT an iterable.  You can use `Object.keys()` to get an array of keys which you can then iterate.

Comment: So you want `let nameGood = dataGood.name.split(','); let userGood = dataGood.user.split(',');`. No need for a loop.

Comment: @FelixKling Wow, Thank you, I didn't know we could do that.

Answer (score 3):

```
for(const [key, value] of Object.entries(dataGood)){
      ...
  }
```

or

```
for(const element of Object.keys(dataGood)){
      ...
  }
```

Comment: it makes it better if a short explanation is included as to why your answer works.

Answer (score 0):

To iterate the object you will have to use [for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop.

```
for(const element in dataGood){
      let name = element.name;
      let user = element.user;
      nameGood.concat(name.split(','));
      userGood.concat(user.split(','));
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but is the name and user aren't array type, I will not be able to use toString() or split() functions.

Comment: Your JSON shows that they are string. `{"name":"something,cool", "user": "Awesome,Great"}`

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

```
  let data =  fs.readFileSync('./data/data.json');
  let dataGood = JSON.parse(data);
  let nameGood = [];
  let userGood = [];
   for (const [key,value] of Object.entries(dataGood)) {
       if(key == "name"){
      let name = [] = value; 
      let nameSplit = name.toString().split(',')
      nameGood = nameSplit;
    }
      if(key == "user")
      let user = [] = value;
      let userSplit = user.toString().split(',')
      userGood = userSplit;
    }
   }
console.log(nameGood, userGood)
}
```

Thank you all for help!

Comment: `let nameGood = dataGood.name.split(','); let userGood = dataGood.user.split(',');` would be much simpler. No need for a loop.